# f:validateRegex does not seem to work

Tags: regex, jsf

why isn't this regex working? I am going crazy over this

```
<p:inputText id="test" validatorMessage="error message">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="msg test" />
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]{1,7}" />
</p:inputText>
```

when I put the value "65432" I get the message I set in `validatorMessage`

I actually intended to use this regex `(\d\d{0,2})(((,\d{3}){0,2})|(\d{0,6}))( USD)?` But I am not even able to make the first one work

---

***EDIT :*** I managed to find my answer. I wrongfuly removed the converter attribute from my code sample. See the answer to this post for more info.

Comment: What is the error message?  The regex looks OK to me, assuming that is the logic you want.

Comment: It's not an error message from the console, I just get the message I set in `validatorMessage`.

I edited the post, I agree it was unclear

Comment: @Sirmyself it might be related to the jsf regex parser. Try using other regex like `[0-9]+`, or `[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?`, or actually try with just 2 digits `[0-9][0-9]`. If any of this work, then it sounds you have maybe a  cache issue?

Comment: You're hiding away the real validation error message with a custom `validatorMessage`. Remove it and retry. It could for instance have a completely different cause and thus contain the clue/answer. To all [regex] users, the `<f:validateRegex>` delegates internally to `java.util.regex.Pattern` so same rules apply as [java][regex].

Comment: I tried a mix of both @BalusC and @Federico_Piazza : I put `"[0-9]+"` and I get the following message after removing my custom one : `{1}: Validation Error: Value not according to pattern ''{0}''`

Comment: I also get the same message with my original pattern

Comment: In future questions please make a habit to prepare and post a fullworthy [mcve]. See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Absolutely, this was just a mistake while I was cleaning the code to make it more readable, I removed a full line by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find my answer. I wrongfuly removed the converter attribute from my code sample. Here is what it should have been :

```
<p:inputText id="test" validatorMessage="error message" converter="someConverter">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="msg test" />
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]{1,7}" />
</p:inputText>
```

It turns out JSF was not validating the regex before going into the converter as I thought. My converter removed commas and put the string value into a Long object. Then, if my understanding is accurate, JSF was trying do compare the Long object with the regex : wich of course returned an invalid answer.